# How to flatten multiple lists with list comprehension in python

Tags: python

I currently have multiple lists that consists of inner lists. I've found out how to use list comprehension to flatten the lists but how can i do it without reusing the same line of code?

Here's an example code:

```
first = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
second = [[3,5,6], [0,3,4]]
third = [[2,5,0], [1,2,9]]

flat_first = [item for sublist in first for item in sublist]
flat_second = [item for sublist in second for item in sublist]
flat_third = [item for sublist in third for item in sublist]
```

Here is what i tried:

```
lists = [first, second, third]
for i in lists:
   flattened = [item for sublist in i for item in sublist]
```

Comment: What's the expected output? A single list with each flattened list nested? A single flattened list from the other three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure witch solution you want, so I came up with two options:

```
# Making a list of lists
first = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
second = [[3,5,6], [0,3,4]]
third = [[2,5,0], [1,2,9]]
lists = [first, second, third]

# Option 1 (a single flattened list)

flattened1 = [item for sublist in lists for subsublist in sublist for item in subsublist]
print(flattened1)
# Output:
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 5, 6, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 1, 2, 9]

# Option 2 (a list of flattened lists)

flattened2 = [[item for subsublist in sublist for item in subsublist] for sublist in lists]
print(flattened2)
# Output:
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 5, 6, 0, 3, 4], [2, 5, 0, 1, 2, 9]]
```

I checked your code too, flattened is being subscribed each interaction, an option to fix it would be:

```
flattened = []
for sublist in lists:
    flattened.append([item for subsublist in sublist for item in subsublist])

print(flattened)
# Output:
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 5, 6, 0, 3, 4], [2, 5, 0, 1, 2, 9]]
```

Let me know if one of these options do help you,
have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, if you don't want to "reuse" the same line of code, you would put it into a function. Assuming you want to "update" the variables `first`, `second`, and `third`, you cannot do so without repeating the variable name (and repeating *something*, like you have in your first example). In this case, might you prefer to use a dictionary? Also, `itertools.chain.from_iterable` is probably fastest:

```py
import itertools

my_lists = {
    'first': [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]],
    'second': [[3,5,6], [0,3,4]],
    'third': [[2,5,0], [1,2,9]],
}

# Put this into an update() function if you want a simple call!
for key, val in my_lists.items():
    my_lists[key] = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(val))
```

Which updates the original dictionary:

```py
>>> my_lists
{'first': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'second': [3, 5, 6, 0, 3, 4], 'third': [2, 5, 0, 1, 2, 9]}
```

Otherwise, if you simply want to use a list comprehension to create *new* variables `flat_first`, `flat_second`, and `flat_third`, you've already done that in your OP, although if you want a one-liner to do that:

```
flat_first, flat_second, flat_third = (list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(val)) for val in [first, second, third])
```

Similar to what Ignatius asked, what exactly is your goal (intended output) here?

```
lists = [first, second, third]
flattened = [[item for sublist in some_list for item in sublist] for some_list in lists]
```

Could also be correct, as commented by Ignatius, which gives you:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 5, 6, 0, 3, 4], [2, 5, 0, 1, 2, 9]]
```

Although you are creating *new* values, which I am not entirely sure is what you want. Unless it is.